# get wordpress comments and trim

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

Many searches and found nothing similar!
I get Some comments on my home page as customer testimonials with code below. and I have two questions.

1- how can I trim comments from for example 60 words above.(cause some of the comment words are higher!)

2-how to get just comments less than 60 words?

```
                <?php
            $comments = get_comments(array(
                'page_id' => 2556,
                'status' => 'approve',
            ));
            
            //Display the list of comments
            wp_list_comments(array(
                'per_page' => 10,
                'avatar_size' => 30,
                'reverse_top_level' => true,
            ), $comments);

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my question NO.1

```
enter code here
            <?php
            $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
            $comments = $comments_query->query(array(
                'post_id' => 2556,
                'status' => 'approve',
                'number' => 10
            )); ?>

            <?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
                <div class="custom-comment">
                <p> <?php echo wp_trim_words($comment->comment_content, 60, '...') ?> </p>
                <div class="custom-comment-author">
                    <span><?php echo $comment->comment_author ?></span>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_avatar_url($comment->comment_author_email); ?>" class="custom-avatar" loading="lazy" alt="">
                </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I will answer if I find any solution of NO.2 but If anyone can answer, it would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' );
?>
```

Comment: wp_list_comments and get_comments return array how to use your code when your code is for string?

Comment: Loop through your comments.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it